# Name html blob urls for easy reference

Tags: javascript, html, blob

Within our web application we load a lot of content from package files (zipped packages containing html, js, css, images and so on.) The module loader (client side JS) processes the packages and makes the content available to the DOM using blob urls.

While this works very nice, it's sometimes tedious to find the right piece of JavaScript file for debugging.

IE: in chrome in the development console->sources all blob urls are listed under (no domain) and have random names such as:

```
blob:https://example.com/0613efd7-6977-4872-981f-519eea0bc911
```

In a normal production environment there are roughly 100 lines like this, so finding the right one might take some time.

I'd pretty much like to name the blob urls, or do something to make them easier to find for debugging purposes. This seems possible since WebPack is doing something like this, however i can't seem to find how. Is there anybody that can hint me in the right direction.

Comment: At the point your extracting and make into a blob, why not just create a reference here.. `var blobs = {"blob:https://example.com/0613efd7-6977-4872-981f-519eea0bc911": "This is the blob"}` etc.

Comment: Hi Keith, thank you for the out of the box answer, i was thinking about something like that as wel, it whould definitively save time searching the right file. However then i saw the implementation of WebPack and liked to really implement the file names and structure. However if i cannot find out how to do that i'll go for your option.

Comment: @Keith that's probably the best solution, you should write it as an answer. I'll mention it in my own answer which is just a hack, but it would make more sense if you care to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have found a solution that works to my liking. For our application we already used a serviceworker which has caching active. So i ended up writing the module files into the serviceworker cache whenever somebody has debug mode turned on.

Since the url portion of the resource files is static this way, all the nice browser features such as breakpoints are now useable again.

Below i've posted the relevant code of the serviceworker. The rest of the code is just plain serviceworker caching.

```
api.serveScript = function(module, script, content){
try{
    content = atob(content);
} catch(err){}

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var init = {
        status: 200,
        statusText: "OK",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'}
    };
    caches.open("modulecache-1").then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching ' + module + "/" + script);
      cache.put("/R/" + module + "/script/" + script, new Response(content, init));
      resolve("/R/" + module + "/script/" + script);
    });
});

}
```

Thanks for your answers and help. I hope this solution is going to help some others too.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the way I would do it is have some global that keeps a track of the URL's, using a simple reverse map.

One problem of course with this is that references to a blob that no longer exists will be kept in memory, but if say you was only enabling this for debugging purposes this might not be a problem.

```js
var namedblobs = {};

function addNamedBlob(name, uri) {
  namedblobs[uri] = name;
}

function getNamedBlob(uri) {
  return namedblobs[uri];
}

function createSomeBlob() {
  //for testing just a random number would do
  return Math.random().toString();
}

var blob = createSomeBlob();

addNamedBlob("test1", blob);
addNamedBlob("test2", createSomeBlob());

console.log(getNamedBlob(blob)); //should be test1
```

Comment: And in worth case, you could overwrite URL.revokeObjectURL so that it clears your map entry.

Answer (score 1):

@Keith's option is probably the best one. (create a Map of your blobURIs and easy to read file names).

You could also do a dynamic router that will point some nice url to the blobURIs, but if you are open to do this, then just don't use blobURIs.

---

An other hackish workaround, really less cleaner than the Map, would be to append a fragment identifier to your blobURI `blob:https://example.com/0613efd7-6977-4872-981f-519eea0bc911#script_name.js`.

**Beware**, This should work for *application/javascript* Blobs or some other resource types, but not for documents (html/svg/...) where this fragment identifier has a special meaning.

```js
var hello = new Blob(["alert('hello')"], {type:'application/javascript'});
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = URL.createObjectURL(hello) + '#hello.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
console.log(script.src);

var css = new Blob(["body{background:red}"], {type:'text/css'});
var style = document.createElement('link');
style.href = URL.createObjectURL(css) + '#style.css';
style.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(style);
console.log(style.href);
```

**[And as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvbds68p/)** for browsers which doesn't like null origined StackSnippet's iframes.

Comment: Using a # fragment was an idea I had, but after testing it appears it doesn't work.   Well here on chrome it doesn't anyway.

Comment: @Keith you are right, chrome won't allow this hack in null origined iframes, works well in jsfiddle and *normal* usage though. (I also had the wrong css MIME, it begins to be late here...)

Comment: Interesting,.. That seems to work.  But if say I go here -> http://bytes.schibsted.com/the-magic-of-createobjecturl/  upload an image, using object inspector add a # fragment to an image, it breaks.  So I wonder if this is broken for images only.. ?

Comment: As I said, it won't work for documents, for sure. For non svg images, I would have thought it would work, but I have to admit I am not entirely sure, even though it might well be an unnoticed and unsignificant bug in chrome implementation (can't test it before tomorrow anymore, do other browsers behave the same?). And IIRC according to specs it should work in given cases (js and css) but once again, it is highly possible that implementations have bugs and don't allow it (like chrome here in SO), but since it a too much security issue, I'm not even sure we can call it a bug.